# How to init xml field of `tns:ArrayOfAnyType`?

Tags: php, xml, soap, wsdl

I'm working with a web service of:

```
<s:element name="Recipients_AddOrUpdate">
  <s:complexType>
    <s:sequence>
      <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="email" type="s:string" />
      <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="groups" type="tns:ArrayOfAnyType" />
    </s:sequence>
  </s:complexType>
</s:element>
```

I'm sending a php request of:

```
$data='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Header>
        <SecHeader xmlns="http://www.inwise.com/schemas">
            <username>'.$userName.'</username>
            <pass>'.$password.'</pass>
        </SecHeader>
    </soap:Header>
    <soap:Body>
        <Recipients_AddOrUpdate xmlns="http://www.inwise.com/schemas">
            <email>foo@foo.com</email>
        </Recipients_AddOrUpdate>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>';
```

My question is how to init the `groups`'s xml node (`tns:ArrayOfAnyType`)?

this syntax is not working:

```
        <Recipients_AddOrUpdate xmlns="http://www.inwise.com/schemas">
            <email>foo@foo.com</email>
            <groups>15245</groups>
        </Recipients_AddOrUpdate>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the groups element is an integer ID, then you should be creating it as...

```
<groups>
   <anyType xsi:type="xsd:int">15245</anyType>
</groups>
```

This is from the example PHP code on their support web site at http://62.219.25.208/Email-Marketing-API/Recipients-Add-Or-Update-Php.aspx